# How to classify the opinions to get the best prediction?

Tags: probability, algorithms, markov-chains, machine-learning, neural-networks

Assume I have four friends, each of them will predict the result of each football match (based on history data, weather data, etc). They will tell me their decisions.

I also have the set of their data history data and weather data. I can also do the similar prediction. However, I want to classify which of my four friend make the right decision instead of predict the football match. (The reason I said that because I do NOT want to put all the data including my friends' decisions into a classify to make the decision. It is because their decisions will be the same weight of the history and weather data. My friends' decisions should weight much more  )

How I can maximize the correct prediction?

Comment: what if none of your friends prediction is correct?

Comment: So there should have 5 possible output, the last one is do not trust any of those four prediction

Answer (score -1):

Your model is highly inefficient. Each of the players prediction has *no* influence on the other players predictions' truthfulness. So instead of inputting them all at once, you should input them sequentially. So:

```
friend1 + other data = output
friend2 + other data = output
friend3 + other data = output
friend4 + other data = output
```

This makes your network smaller, making the training happen in less iterations and in a less amount of time.

But still. **You shouldn't input your friends prediction at all**. The only thing that your network is doing is comparing it's own prediction with your friends prediction internally.

In what way should your friends' predictions add anything useful to the (each others) output?

Comment: The way you did will make the friends' decisions as the same weight of the data. Moreover, each friend gives a decision. The way you did is not getting result from their decision.

Comment: Are you familiar with neural networks? What makes you think that the friends decision have the same weight on the output just because i divided them? There is NO way you can control the weight of a certain input - this is what the neural network will figure out for you (a neural network is a black box). Your proposed model simply doesnt make sense.

Comment: Did I say that we need to limit ourselves to use neural network? I read more paper this week. I found that I can use genetic algorithm to do a weight optimaization for a few preset situation and I can use other classifier to predetermine the situation.In other words, the 'other' classifier is to choose the opinion weight set from GA. Weight x opinion will be the final result.